# Meteor : Publish data from external source (socket)

Tags: sockets, meteor, publish-subscribe, ddp

I am using the getstream.io API with their library. They have the following hook in their JS library :

```
newsFeed.subscribe(function callback(data) {
        //do something with the data   
 });
```

I created a package to wrap the NPM library.
I want now to use this function and publish the results to a client only collection.

I'm going to try this but I don't know if it's ok :

```
Meteor.publish("newsFeed", function () {
  var self = this;
  var newsFeed = GetstreamClient.feed('notification', 'newsFeed');
  //TODO : Use MeteorAsync ?
  newsFeed.subscribe(function callback(data) {
        self.added("clientNewsCollection", Random.id(), {event: data});
    });
  self.ready();
});
```

Is this ok ? Or should I do it this way ?

```
// This will be used to store the subscription objects for later management
var subs = { };

// The helper publication
Meteor.publish('newsFeed', function() {

       var subscription = this;
       subs[subscription._session.id] = subscription;

       subscription.onStop(function() {
          delete subs[subscription._session.id];
       });
});

var newsFeed = GetstreamClient.feed('notification', 'newsFeed');
//TODO : Use MeteorAsync ?
 newsFeed.subscribe(function callback(data) {
        for (var subscriptionID in subs) {
             var subscription = subs[subscriptionID];
             subscription.added("clientNewsCollection", Random.id(), {event: data});
        }
  });
```